# React importing selected values in a table

Tags: reactjs, key-value, reactstrap, stripe-payments

The data I get with the API `this.state = {items: [] }`

I'm transferring it.

Then I transfer these values to the table. But I can't get the value of the data I choose?
How can I get the value of the selected row with the "Open" button I transferred to the table?

do I get the value of the data I selected when I click the edit button?

```
`
    this.state = {
    items: []
    };
    this.debtModalForm = this.debtModalForm.bind(this);


    debtModalForm() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
    modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
    }

    render() {
    return(

       <div className={"animated fadeIn container-fluid"}>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <Card>
                        <CardHeader>
                          <i className="fa fa-align-justify" /> Customer Debt
                        </CardHeader>

                        <CardBody>
                          <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th width={"10"} />
                                <th width={"15"}>No</th>
                                <th style={{ display: "none" }}>User</th>
                                <th style={{ display: "none" }}>Key</th>
                                <th style={{ display: "none" }}>CreatedUserKey</th>
                                <th width={"40"}>Total Debt</th>
                                <th width={"40"}>Received amount</th>
                                <th scope={"row"}>Description</th>
                                <th width={"20"}>Payment Date</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>


                            <tbody>
                              {items.map(item => (

                                  <tr key={item.id}>
                                    <td>
                                      <Button
                                          block
                                          color="info"
                                          onClick={this.debtModalForm}
                                      >
                                        {" "}
                                        Edit
                                        {
                                          <Modal
                                              isOpen={this.state.modal}
                                              toggle={this.debtModalForm}
                                              backdrop={"static"}
                                          >
                                            <ModalHeader toggle={this.debtModalForm}>
                                              {this.props.customerInfo.customer.ID} number customer
                                            </ModalHeader>
                                            <ModalBody>

                                              <Row>
                                                <Col xs="2">TotalDebt</Col>
                                                <Col xs="6">
                                                  <Input
                                                      type={"text"}
                                                      placeholder={"Total Debt"}
                                                      name={"totalDebt"}
                                                      defaultValue={item.totalDebt}
                                                      //value={this.state.items.totalDebt}
                                                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                  />
                                                </Col>
                                              </Row>

                                              <Row>
                                                <Col xs="2">ReceivedAmount</Col>
                                                <Col xs="6">
                                                  <Input
                                                      type={"text"}
                                                      placeholder={"ReceivedAmount"}
                                                      name={"receivedAmount"}
                                                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                  />
                                                </Col>
                                              </Row>

                                              <Row>
                                                <Col xs="2">Description</Col>
                                                <Col xs="6">
                                                  <Input
                                                      type={"textarea"}
                                                      name={"description"}
                                                      defaultValue={item.description}
                                                      rows={"2"}
                                                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                  />
                                                </Col>
                                              </Row>

                                              <Row>
                                                <Col xs="2">Payment Date</Col>
                                                <Col xs="6">
                                                  <Input
                                                      type={"date"}
                                                      name={"paymentDate"}
                                                      defaultValue={item.paymentDate}
                                                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                                                  />
                                                </Col>
                                              </Row>

                                            </ModalBody>

                                            <ModalFooter>
                                              <Button
                                                  color="primary"
                                                  onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                                              > Kaydet
                                              </Button>{" "}
                                              <Button
                                                  color="secondary"
                                                  onClick={this.debtModalForm}
                                              > Close
                                              </Button>
                                            </ModalFooter>
                                          </Modal>
                                        }
                                      </Button>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                                    <td style={{ display: "none" }}>{item.user}</td>
                                    <td style={{ display: "none" }}>{item.debtKey}</td>
                                    <td style={{ display: "none" }}>
                                      {item.createduserKey}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{item.totalDebt}</td>
                                    <td>{item.receivedAmount}</td>
                                    <td>{item.description}</td>
                                    <td>{new Date(item.paymentDate).toLocaleString()}</td>
                                  </tr>


                              ))}
                            </tbody>


                          </Table>
                        </CardBody>
                      </Card>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </div>
    )
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you are creating a modal for every row on the table and you are using `this.state.modal` to show it which it's shared between all the rows and will show all the modal's at once,instead, you can just have on Modal and you can pass the active selected row data on it

if want to keep the current component structure

```js
 toggleActiveItemModal = (id)=>{
    this.setState({
    activeItemModal : this.state.activeItemModal === id ? undefined : id
    })
  }

 <Modal
   isOpen={this.state.activeItemModal === item.id}
   toggle={this.toggleActiveItemModal(item.id)}
>
...rest of the modal
</Modal>
```